# How can I do a \forall look bigger?

Tags: math-mode, miktex, math-operators

When I am using the math mode and I'm writing, for example, the lipschitz function definition:

```
$$ d'(f(x), f(y)) \leq L d(x,y) \forall x,y \in X $$
```

then I run it and the \forall looks small...

What should I do ? Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastiano!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `relsize` package with the command `\mathlarger`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\[ d'(f(x), f(y)) \leq L d(x,y),\, \mathlarger{\forall} x,y \in X \]
\end{document}
```

But if you want it monstrously big  you could use

[image]

`\mathlarger{\mathlarger\forall}`.